# Is there a way to know the context of an Akka actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have an actor with some contexts, i.e.

```
def step2: Receive = {
  case _ => log error "Unhandled message"
}

def step1: Receive = {
  case _ => log error "Unhandled message"
}
```

Is there a way to know on which state the actor currently is (step1, step2)?
(I could stock the value on a `string` but I wonder if there is a better way.)

If it not possible, I would like to understand why since this state should be kept somewhere.

Comment: It's called *encapsulation* and it's a feature: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html#Actor_Best_Practices

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand you comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## FSM

You can use `FSM`. `stateName` gives the name of the state.

Ping the Actor with some special message handled in every state to send the stateName.

```
sealed trait ExampleState
case object State1 extends ExampleState
case object State2 extends ExampleState
case object C extends ExampleState

import akka.actor.{Actor, FSM}
import akka.event.EventHandler
import akka.util.duration._

case object Move

class ABC extends Actor with FSM[ExampleState, Unit] {

  import FSM._

  startWith(State1, Unit)

  when(State1) {
    case Ev(Move) =>
      EventHandler.info(this, "Go to B and move on after 5 seconds")
      goto(state2) forMax (5 seconds)
  }

  when(State2) {
    case Ev(StateTimeout) =>
      EventHandler.info(this, "Moving to C")
      goto(C)
  }

  when(C) {
    case Ev(Move) =>
      EventHandler.info(this, "Stopping")
      stop
  }

  initialize // this checks validity of the initial state and sets up timeout if needed
}
```

## Hacky Solution

Akka Actor does not store any specific information about the PartialFunction. So I don't think there will be a akka lib function readily available for this.

Have `state` inside the actor and then update the state when Actor tries to become something.

```
class FooBar extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var state: Option[String] = Some("receive")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ => context become state1()
  }

  def state1: () => Receive = {
    () => {

      state = Some("state1")

      {
        case _ => log error "ignore"
      }
    }
  }


  def state2: () => Receive = {
    () => {

      state = Some("state2")

      {
        case _ => log error "ignore"
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Ok, if  nobody gives an other solution I will accept your answer, but this state has to be kept somewhere and accessible by the actor, so why is it not possible to get it?

Comment: @Simon You can have a case in each state which will send the state data outside actor using Actor message

Comment: @Simon you can use FSM.

Comment: Yep; it's probably a cleaner solution if there is no way to get the stateName in a traditional actor. I'm curious to know why it is not possible to get it in a traditional actor, so I will accept your answer tomorrow. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Simon traditional actor does not maintain stateName while FSM  maintains the state name. My Hacky solution is some what closer to the fsm implementation

Comment: I understood that... I just wanted to know why this does not exist on traditional actors since this state has to be kept somewhere.